# How to revert a merge with git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I've been working in a branch that has many commits.
Once pushed and merged to 'master', what's the best option to revert changes all merged commits from the branch i was working in 'master'?

What about this?

```
git revert -m 1 <merge-commit>
```

Comment: HAve you pushed the commits or are they still lying locally?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by first merging your branch in using the --no-ff option.

```
git merge --no-ff your-dev-branch
```

What this does is create whats called a merge commit for you. If you want to revert the merge, you only have to revert that merge commit. If you don't specify the --no-ff flag, then there may be a chance that it doesn't create the merge commit.